# Why does "if exists" fail with a false positive?

Tags: macos, applescript

The file, "Test.file" in the below code does not exist, yet the script returns true. Why? What am I doing wrong?

```
set thePath to (path to application support folder from user domain)

if exists thePath & "Test.file" then
display dialog "The file was found!" buttons {"OK"} default button 1
else
display dialog "The was file wasn't found." buttons {"OK"} default button 1
end if
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to reference a file for the test to function properly.

```
set thePath to path to application support folder from user domain
tell application "System Events" to exists file ((thePath as text) & "Test.file")
```

With the conditional:

```
set thePath to path to application support folder from user domain
tell application "System Events" to exists file ((thePath as text) & "Test.file")
if the result then
    display dialog "The file was found!" buttons {"OK"} default button 1
else
    display dialog "The was file wasn't found." buttons {"OK"} default button 1
end if
```

Comment: The code does not compile with conditional.

Comment: I have added the syntax for the conditional.